# Error in fetching beans from xml file in spring

Tags: java, android, spring, javabeans

I am new to spring. I created `config.xml` in which I created beans. When I tried to use `getBean`, I was getting the following error:

> IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
> [config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class
> path resource [config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

I was using this line earlier.

```
ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(" config.xml");

Student Student1=(Student) context.getBean("s1");
```

Then, I changed the code to this:

```
ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*: config.xml");
```

But, now i am getting new error:
**No bean named 's1' available**

My main function is present in `src/main/java/org/example/App.java`

My config.xml is present in `src/main/java/config.xml`

Content of `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="s1" class="org.example.Student"> <!--org.example is groupId-->
    <property name="studentId">
        <value>22344</value>
    </property>
    <property name="studentName">
        <value>AP</value>
    </property>
    <property name="studentAddress">
        <value>L</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: please provide contents of config.xml. It should have  a bean defined with ``id="s1"``

Comment: Hi Pratap, I have provided the content. Can you please look into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put the xml file `config.xml` into **src/main/resources** (by default maven look for you Java source files into `src/main/java` and for your resource files into `src/main/resources`)

You don't need the `classpath` keyword when creating the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` object, juste use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml")` like below :

```
ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
Student student1=(Student) context.getBean("s1");
System.out.println(student1.getStudentId());
```

Comment: Hi Olivier, I did according to what you said, but still the same issue. Do I need to change anything in my config.xml?

Comment: I ran it into my computer and it works perfectly. I used `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");` you can see it in my answer. I see in your initial post an unecessary space before config.xml : `(" config.xml")` instead of `("config.xml")`,